# implementation of global variables in an HTML document with Javascript tags of different types

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, script-tag

**The situation :** I use a script (a) in an HTML document to be able to use a particular SDK. Then I use a second script (b) basic to be able to create a Kendo UI table.

**My problem :** I try to pass data from script (a) to script (b) via global variables but it doesn't work, what can I do?

Info that might help you:

- my document is a form framed by  tags
- I use Camunda. The first script allows me to use the SDK to retrieve the ID of the instance associated with the form being processed. (but I don't think this is the crux of the problem)
- I assume that both scripts are read at the same time by the browser, and that's why script (b) can't read the variable simply because it is not yet created in script (a).

**The code :**

```
    
        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        var taskService = camForm.client.resource('task');
        var processInstanceId = null;
        var result = null;
        taskService.get(camForm.taskId, function(err, task) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(task));
            debugger;
            processInstanceId = task.processInstanceId;
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/"+processInstanceId+"/variables", function(result) {
                debugger;
                window.alert("coucou");
                console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);
            });
            debugger;
            console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);
            debugger;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);
            //this is where I implement the Kendo UI grid
    </script>
    <div id="grid"></div>
```

I cannot read the content of the result variable in script (b) because it is not defined.

How do I do this?

Comment: does any of the `console.log` actually log the value? I see 3 of them

Comment: * the first one displays the right value. It is the 3rd to be executed if I have observed correctly.
* the 2nd indicates that the JsonWeightSetpoints field does not exist. I guess it's because it's the 2nd to be executed. and at that time the result value is set to null.
* the 3rd indicates that result is not defined, it means that it is the first to be executed. 

I think that the observation shows that in fact the problem comes from the reading order of the scripts, but how to determine a reading order of the Script tags?

Comment: I see. So why not writing the logic you want at the first console.log? so instead of having a 3rd script, just continue working right after `$.get` callback

Comment: the problem is specified in the post, how to make pass the value of my variable in the script (b) ? console.log are there only for information, I summarized my code to simplify the presentation of the problem. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: The needed value is returned after an asynchronous call, which takes some x time, however, your code in the 3rd script is executed synchronously which obviously doesn't wait for the value to get returned. Have you tried using a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)? basically, you would declare an event and its logic in the 3rd script, then trigger that event only when the value is ready! if this solution suits your need I will add an answer with an example, cheers

Comment: Yes I would be very interested in an example please :-) We agree that I only have the choice between 2 events? 
* user-triggered event such as a click for example?
* timer event like settimeout for example?

There is no conditional event?Like for example if a variable becomes true then I execute the function?

Comment: I added an answer with an example, of course, you can trigger the event when a certain condition is met, use `if` to check your value and decide accordingly cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Custom events solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script cam-script type="text/javascript">
        var taskService = camForm.client.resource('task');
        var processInstanceId = null;
        var result = null;
        taskService.get(camForm.taskId, function(err, task) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(task));
            debugger;
            processInstanceId = task.processInstanceId;
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/"+processInstanceId+"/variables", function(result) {
                debugger;
                window.alert("coucou");
                console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);

                // the value is available here, we now can trigger an event and send it
              document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("handler", {
                detail: { value: result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value }
              }));
            });
            debugger;
            console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);
            debugger;
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(result.JsonWeightSetpoints.value);
  //this is where I implement the Kendo UI grid

  // event listener, this would get executed only when we want
  document.addEventListener("handler", function(event) {
    // write you logic here
    console.log(event.detail.value);
  });
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

useful resources:

1. [MDN: Creating and triggering
   events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)
2. [Introducing asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)